# Server Component imported into a This doesn't work: Client component and wrapped in a Client component

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, react-server-components

I tried doing this in my Next 13 website but it's not working.

```
// This pattern doesn't work:

// Parent Client Component.
'use client';

import ClientComponent from './client-component'
import ServerComponent from './server-component'

export default function Page() {
return ( 
<ClientComponent>
<ServerComponent />
</ClientComponent> 
)
 }
```

Any reason why this doesn't work? It only works when I convert the parent component to a server component by removing the 'use client' directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#supported-pattern-passing-server-components-to-client-components-as-props say you cannot pass server component in a client component

```
// Parent Client Component.
// You cannot pass server component inside a client component
use client;

import ClientComponent from './client-component'
import ServerComponent from './server-component'

export default function Page() {
 return ( 
  <ClientComponent>
    <ServerComponent />
  </ClientComponent> 
 )
}
```

As above code you provided says it is a "**CLIENT COMPONENT**" that's why this pattern doesn't work.

Comment: But I wrapped the server component inside a client component using the `{children}` prop, which the document says is the accepted pattern. Unless I missed something.

Comment: Look again the component you are mounting in is itself a client component.

Comment: Okay I get you. So that means in a situation like this, I should make sure the client component that wraps the sever component should be imported INTO A SERVER COMPONENT? I tried it and it worked.

Comment: Great! make sure to mark the answer correct so others can find the it quickly.